# Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: python, django

How can I fix it?

#### Error message

> Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['shopping_mall/top_cloth/(?P[0-9]+)/comment\Z', 'top_cloth/(?P[0-9]+)/comment\Z']

Error in line 60

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'add_comment' pk=product.pk %}">add comment</a>
```

#### My URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('top_cloth/', views.top_cloth),
        path('top_cloth/<int:pk>/', views.cloth_detail, name='top_cloth_pk'),
        path('top_cloth/<int:pk>/comment', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
        path('top_cloth/<int:pk>/remove/', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
        path('top_cloth/<int:pk>/modify/', views.comment_modify, name='comment_modify'),
    
    ]
```

#### My views

```
def cloth_detail(request, pk):
        post = ProductList.objects.get(pk=pk)
        product = Comment.objects.order_by()
        return render(
            request,
            'shopping_mall/cloth_detail.html',
            {
                'post': post, 'product': product
            }
        )
    
    def add_comment(request, pk):
        product = get_object_or_404(ProductList, pk=pk)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CommentFrom(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.author = request.user
                comment.product = product
                comment.save()
                return redirect('index', pk=product.pk)
            else:
                form = CommentFrom()
    
            return render(request, 'shopping_mall/add_comment.html', {'form':form})
```

#### Traceback

```
 Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/shopping_mall/top_cloth/1/
    
    Django Version: 4.0.4
    Python Version: 3.9.7
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'crispy_forms',
     'shopping_mall',
     'single_pages',
     'allauth',
     'allauth.account',
     'allauth.socialaccount',
     'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
     'django_summernote']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
    
    
    Template error:
    In template D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\shopping_mall\templates\shopping_mall\cloth_detail.html, error at line 60
       Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['shopping_mall/top_cloth/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment\\Z', 'top_cloth/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment\\Z']
       50 :                 {{ comment.text|linebreaks }}
       51 :             </p>
       52 :         </dlv>
       53 :         {% endif %}
       54 : 
       55 :       {% empty %}
       56 :     <p>Not yet comment</p>
       57 :     {% endfor %}
       58 :     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       59 : 
       60 :         <a class="btn btn-success" href=" {% url 'add_comment' pk=product.pk %} "> Add comment</a>
       61 :     {% else %}
       62 :     <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="btn btn-danger">please login</a>
       63 :     {% endif %}
       64 : </section>
       65 : {% endblock %}
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\shopping_mall\views.py", line 29, in cloth_detail
        return render(
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
        return template.render(context, request)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 62, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
        return nodelist.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
        return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 472, in render
        url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
        return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\github\kys-shoppingmall\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 802, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
    
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /shopping_mall/top_cloth/1/
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['shopping_mall/top_cloth/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment\\Z', 'top_cloth/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment\\Z']
```

<sub>I have been searching on the Internet for a week for a solution to this question, but I can't fix it.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `product.pk` is the empty string, therefore the regex `top_cloth/<int:pk>/comment` doesn't match (`int` means `[0-9]+` therefore needs at least one character).

Therefore there is no url found (hence the error).

Now, why your product.pk is empty ? I see you try to render `cloth_detail.html`, and in the view you wrote :

`product = Comment.objects.order_by()`

Your `product` is then a **list** of `Comment` ? A list has no pk (hence the error).

Let's see your `cloth_detail.html` because I'm thinking there is some logic error in there too.

Comment: Thats right i try ro render cloth_detial.html product = Comment.objects.order_by() How can o fix?

Comment: We need to see your html to understand what you want to do. In your python, "product" is the list of all comments in the database, not a Product.